# c++ + OpenCV 2.4: How to equalizeHist an IplImage* type?

Tags: c++, opencv, mat, iplimage

I wrote the function to equalizeHist an IplImage* type, but everytime I start the program it breaks with

> Unhandled exception at at 0x75454598 in OpenCV+OpenMP+Moments_Test.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x00B8E6C0.

Please, help me to convert IplImage -> Mat -> IplImage properly!

```
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>

using namespace std;

void equalizeHistogramm(IplImage* img){
IplImage* buf = cvCloneImage(img);
cv::Mat mat(img);
cv::Mat buf1(img);
cv::equalizeHist(mat, buf1);
IplImage buf2 = buf1;
img = &buf2;}
```

Comment: you should not use IplImages **at all** in your code. please stick with cv::Mat consistently.

Comment: But image which I have to process is in IplImage. I cannot not to use IplImage at all(((

Comment: see, there's 3 errors already in 6 lines of code: a) you're aliasing the input img, so you can't properly release it afterwards b) you're assigning the address of a local variable, which will be invalid after you leave the function 3)cv::Mat buf1 will self-destruct itself, so your data will be invalid. - again, please, get rid of it all.

Comment: Actually, this function(it is terrible code, I understood) is a part of a big project which i wrote about a week. So, please, help me to convert it, it is the only way. May be, some tutorals or urticles?

Comment: if your input is a cv::Mat , and you output is an (empty) cv::Mat, it's just `cv::equalizeHist(src,dst);` you don't even need a function for this. better clean up the rest of your code.